# Is there a way to use, inside a function, "isdefined(:x)", where x is defined in the same function?

Tags: julia

I have a function that looks for a file named "global" in parent directories of the working dir. This is how I imagined it:

```
function readglobal()
  if isfile("./global")
    text = readdlm("./global",String,comment_char='/')
  else
    for i = 1:8
      if isfile("../"^i * "global")
        text = readdlm("../"^i * "global",String,comment_char='/')
        break
      end
    end
  end

  isdefined(:text) || error("Could not find global file")

  dict = Dict{String,String}()
  for i in 1:size(text)[1]
    dict[text[i,1]] = text[i,2]
  end
  return dict
end
```

This doesn't work because *isdefined* looks for global variables in the current_module(), where I call the function from. 
Is there a way to make it work as intended? To evalute *isdefined(:text)* inside the function?

---

I worked around this with the following code, but I think the code above is cleaner.

```
function readglobal()
  foundit = isfile("./global")
  if foundit
    text = readdlm("./global",String,comment_char='/')
    foundit=true
  else
    for i = 1:8
      foundit = isfile("../"^i * "global")
      if foundit
        text = readdlm("../"^i * "global",String,comment_char='/')
        break
      end
    end
  end

  foundit || error("Could not find global file")

  dict = Dict{String,String}()
  for i in 1:size(text)[1]
    dict[text[i,1]] = text[i,2]
  end
  return dict
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.7 of Julia has a `@isdefined variable_name` macro that is able to do precisely what I asked for in this question. It should work for any local variable.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a 1.5-line version of this function:

```
readglobal() = Dict(mapslices(x->=>(x...),readdlm(first(filter(isfile,
  "./$("../"^i)global" for i=0:8)),String;comment_char='/'),2))
```

It even returns an error if the file is missing ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Somehow I missed that you found the workaround, as you call it, which is pretty much the same as I suggested. I disagree that the first code is cleaner, using `isdefined` seems hacky to me. A `foundit` flag is the right way, IMHO.

**Original answer:**
Don't use `isdefined` to check whether the file has been found. Instead set a flag, e.g. `filefound`. Something along these lines (warning, untested):

```
function readglobal()
    filefound = false
    filepath = "global"
    for i in 0:8
        filefound = isfile(filepath)
        if filefound
            break
        end
        filepath = joinpath("..", filepath)
    end
    filefound || error("Could not find file ")
    text = readdlm(filepath, String, comment_char='/')

    dict = Dict{String,String}()
    for i in 1:size(text, 1)
        dict[text[i,1]] = text[i,2]
    end
    return dict
end
```

**Edit 2:** Here's a variant:

```
function readglobal(filename, maxtries=8)
    tries = 0
    while !isfile(filename) && (tries+=1) <= maxtries
        filename = joinpath("..", filename)
    end
    tries > maxtries || error("Could not find file ")

    text = readdlm(filename, ...
    ...
end
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize how slow `joinpath` was! It seems to be doing a _lot_ more than I thought. It's still cleaner to build the `filepath` variable incrementally, though, rather than generating it in full on each iteration.

Comment: I think you're right, this use of `isdefined` is hacky and a flag fits more properly. But I still think there might be cases where it would be good for `isdefined` to look for symbol assignments inside the scope where it is called from, in this case the function.

And about generating the path incrementally: does that really make a difference? In my mind, since strings are immutable, there is no such thing as "incrementing" string, since every time a new one is created. Am I guessing it right?
Maybe one way to overcome this is to create the largest string first and use substring on it.

Comment: By 'incrementally' I mean performing `file = "../"*file` once per iteration, instead of `"../"*file`, then `"../"^2*file`, ..., then `"../"^n*file`. When `n=8` the performance difference is trivial, but the first way scales linearly, while your way scales exponentially. I also find the former more elegant. Unfortunately I cannot answer your actual question about `isdefined`, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer, but I would use a separate function:

```
function get_global_content()
    if isfile("./global")
      return readdlm("./global",String,comment_char='/')
    else
      for i = 1:8
        if isfile("../"^i * "global")
          return readdlm("../"^i * "global",String,comment_char='/')
        end
      end
    end
    error("Could not find global file")
end

function readglobal()
  text = get_global_content()

  dict = Dict{String,String}()
  for i in 1:size(text)[1]
    dict[text[i,1]] = text[i,2]
  end
  return dict
end
```

Alternatively, have a look at `Nullable`, e.g.,

```
function readglobalnull()
  text = Nullable()
  if isfile("./global")
    text = Nullable(readdlm("./global",String,comment_char='/'))
  else
    for i = 1:8
      if isfile("../"^i * "global")
        text = Nullable(readdlm("../"^i * "global",String,comment_char='/'))
        break
      end
    end
  end

  isnull(text) && error("Could not find global file")
  text = get(text)

  dict = Dict{String,String}()
  for i in 1:size(text)[1]
    dict[text[i,1]] = text[i,2]
  end
  return dict
end
```